# Prevent symbol conversions with GET

Tags: php, get, symbols

When I pass a value via GET, it automatically coverts symbols such as & and = to %26 and %3D in the URL. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['school'] . "&canteen_location=" . $row['canteen_location'] . "'>" . $row['school'] . " - " . $row['canteen_location'] . "</option>";
```

I'm trying to pass through two parameters through only one option. If I knew AJAX I would have two separate forms with the second one (canteen location) being based off of the first one (school)...but I don't.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you right you could just [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) the value in PHP when the form's submitted.

Comment: How could I get this in before the next page loads...or do I put it around the whole line of text I quoted?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean but you'd get your original option value using something like `$value = urldecode($_POST['select_name']);`

Comment: Ahhhhh sorry, I understand. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't proceed in this direction; *one* alternative:

#### html

```
<select name="school">
  <option value="glendale_loc1">GlenDale - Loc 1</option>
  <option value="glendale_loc2">GlenDale - Loc 2</option>
  <option value="weho_loc3">WeHo - Loc 3</option>
  <option value="weho_loc4">WeHo - Loc 4</option>
</select>
```

#### php

```
list($school,$canteen)=explode('_',$_GET['school']);
```

Comment: The idea is a school can have multiple canteens (middle school, senior school for example) and then another school can also have the same canteen locations (middle school, senior school).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Use JavaScript to handle the form and request the appropriate URL if you have to.

Comment: You should mention server side decoding, though. It's a good option, especially since people aren't required to have JavaScript.

Comment: I had assumed he was GETing a URL out of his control... otherwise why would he need to do something like this anyway?  The scenario makes no sense.